# Yii page for incorrect url

Tags: yii

I want 404 page for incorrect url. If I type `http://mysite.com/some-incorrect-url` I want 404 page. How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii handles invalid URLs through the [`errorHandler`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#getErrorHandler-detail) application component; you can read the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CErrorHandler) for it to see where to place the view that will be displayed on a 404.

If you need to configure the error handler component you can do that from your main application configuration file.